# Java Applet not displaying panel components

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, applet

I have an assignment where I have to design an applet which cycles through employee information from a text file. I think my code for reading input from the text file is correct, however I am having trouble displaying the information through GUI. I think the main problem is that I initially designed this as a swing application but I'm having trouble converting it into an Applet. Any suggestions will help thanks.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class UpdateEmp extends JApplet {

static final ArrayList<Record> recordList = new ArrayList<>();
static int currentRecord = 0;

private JTextArea empIdField;
private JTextArea telephoneField;
private JTextArea nameField; 
private JTextArea yowField;

public class display extends JPanel {

    public display() {

        GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints layoutConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);


        empIdField = new JTextArea();
        layoutConstraints.gridx = 0;
        layoutConstraints.gridy = 0;
        add(empIdField, layoutConstraints);

        telephoneField = new JTextArea();
        layoutConstraints.gridx = 0;
        layoutConstraints.gridy = 1;
        add(telephoneField, layoutConstraints);

        nameField = new JTextArea();
        layoutConstraints.gridx = 0;
        layoutConstraints.gridy = 2;
        add(nameField, layoutConstraints);

        yowField = new JTextArea();
        layoutConstraints.gridx = 0;
        layoutConstraints.gridy = 3;        
        add(yowField, layoutConstraints);

    }
}

public void init() {
    System.out.println("Initializing");
    display d = new display();
    getContentPane().add(d);
}

public void start() {

}

public void stop() {

}

public void destory() {

}


public void RecordArray() throws FileNotFoundException {
    File inputFile = new File("Emp.txt");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);

    while(in.hasNextLine()) {

        String line = in.nextLine();

        String[] peopleInfo = line.split("\\s");

        int empId = Integer.parseInt(peopleInfo[0]);
        String telephone = peopleInfo[1];
        String name = peopleInfo[2];
        int years_of_Work = Integer.parseInt(peopleInfo[3]);

        recordList.add(new Record(empId, telephone, name, years_of_Work));

    }

}    

private void showRecord() {
    assert currentRecord >= 0 && currentRecord < recordList.size();
    Record record = recordList.get(currentRecord);

    empIdField.setText(Integer.toString(record.getEmpId()));
    telephoneField.setText(record.getTelephone());
    nameField.setText(record.getName());
    yowField.setText(Integer.toString(record.getYears()));

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException  {   

   //In replacement of app.ShowGui();
   JFrame frame = new JFrame("UpdateEMP");
   frame.setVisible(true);
   frame.setSize(600,400);
   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

   UpdateEmp app = new UpdateEmp();

   app.RecordArray();

   app.init();

   app.showRecord();



   System.out.println(recordList.get(currentRecord).getEmpId());



   }

}
```

Comment: FYI: [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free)

Comment: `getContentPane().setLayout(layout);` would be your first mistake, you shouldn't be calling this from within the context of the `display`, but should be calling `setLayout` directly (which affects the `JPanel` and not the `JApplet`)

Comment: You `main` method is your next problem, applets are suppose to embedded within web browsers, so they don't "show" up by themselves.  Personally, I'd drop the `JApplet` altogether and simply add `display` to your `JFrame` instead

Comment: Applets also, typically, run within a tight security model which generally prevents you from reading/writing files

Comment: @MadProgrammer *"..prevents you from reading/writing files"* True. We usually access resources by URL for applets. Use the document base or code base to form an relative URL to the `Emp.txt`. *"I have an assignment.."* From a teacher? It is about time they updated their notes. If it's due to the teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). If the teacher is resisting this advice, challenge ***them*** to make an applet that you can visit on the web,

Comment: Note: Applets should not have a constructor, as it is not guaranteed to be called on the EDT. Move all that code into the `init()` method.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Sorry, should have clarified "local files" :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer I was trying to decide whether to explain that the applet will only ever be able to access files on the client machine. A `File` cannot ever point back to the server, where an application resource like this would presumably be located. This is a really poorly thought out exercise to assign to students, any way you cut it..

Comment: @AndrewThompson It's really poorly thought out exercise to give to anybody :P